# ERROR: syntax error at or near "ALL" postgres GRANT psql 8.4.15

Tags: postgresql, sql-grant, postgresql-8.4

I have a postgresql version 8.4.15 database and when I want to give a user permissions on tables, I get a syntax error that in postgres version 11.5 it doesn't.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALL"
LINE 1: GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO consulta;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALL"
LINE 1: GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO consulta;
```

Comment: That syntax is simply not supported in 8.4. Besides: that version is [no longer supported or maintained](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  - you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: There would be the alternative to use `psql`'s `\gexec` - alas, that also didn't exist in 8.4.

Comment: it is not possible to upgrade to a new version at this time, any other options?